# Oracle - MyBatis Insert statement with auto increment id

Tags: angularjs, oracle, oracle10g, mybatis, spring-mybatis

Oracle Version: 10g.

in my Mapper.xml

```
<insert id="insert" useGeneratedKeys="true">
<selectKey keyProperty="id" resultType="int" order="BEFORE">
       SELECT AUTO_INCR.nextVal from dual;
</selectKey>
INSERT INTO TABLE1(id,email,subject)
VALUES(#{id},#{email},#{subject})
</insert>
```

My table structure in oracle:

id     PK      NUMBER

email         Varchar2

subject       Varchar2

I also have a sequence created named:**AUTO_INCR**

But this returns me with a error: 
**ORA-0091 invalid Character**

i called it at my page by:

```
http.post({
     method: 'POST',
     url: 'myurl',  
     data: {
       email: email,
       subject : subject
}
})
```

Any idea how to carry on ?? 
I tried to research on the error but to no avail , i couldn't solve it.

Comment: "But this returns me with a error: ORA-0091 invalid Character". Which code or something are you referring using 'this' ? Did you mean the code inside mapper.xml?

Comment: i call it with http.post at my other pages in order to insert a data into oracle db

Comment: Try again removing `;` from `from dual;`. And the previous edit was more readable and you just reverted it.

Comment: i tried removing the ; . it works for the first insert. But the subsequent insert was not successful because the ID did not increment. What can i do to increment the id ? @JSapkota